# Is gameObject equivalent to this in the script of the GameObject it is attached to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had a question with regard to the use of `gameObject` as inherited from `MonoBehaviour` when writing Unity scripts.

In some tutorials, for example for making a scaling health bar, we retrieve the original scale of the health bar as follows:

```
originalScale = gameObject.transform.localScale.x;
```

I toyed around with this a little bit and figured that, since I'm getting the transform of the object I'm currently manipulating, I could also use `this`:

```
originalScale = this.transform.localScale.x;
```

In Unity, are these two always equivalent (at least when implementing `MonoBehaviour`)? Is it simply more common to use `gameObject` so that it is clear what we are referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `this` refers to the object described in the script. All Monobehaviour
>   scripts are components, and the `this` keyword refers to the current
>   component that's executing the code.
>
> `gameObject` is the game object in the scene. Game objects have
>   components attached to them. From within a Monobehaviour script, you
>   can access the game object that the script is attached to by using
>   either `this.gameObject` or `gameObject` which are equivalent.

[Reference](http://www.completeunitydeveloper.com/blog/this-vs-gameobject), since it was said better than I would.

---

Regarding `transform`, this is also a Component. Since GameObject is just a container for components, when you do `gameObject.transform` your are refering that transform component.

Because any GameObject have only one transform, `this.transform` will happen to points to that same component as well.

This is a special case and it's because MonoBehaviour actually inherits from Component, which utilmately if you look at Component class

```
// Summary:
//     ///
//     The Transform attached to this GameObject (null if there is none attached).
//     ///
public Transform transform { get; }
```

So that's why you are getting the same result in both case.

Comment: Interesting. I noticed, however, that when using `this` (not `this.gameObject`) in the manner I described above, the outcome in the game was identical. Do you know if this  was simply a coincidence (i.e., the object in the script happened to be the same one as in the scene), or am I missing something?

Comment: @user991710 Good point, I actually forgot to mention that part, I added more info in my post regarding this. Everything is there now :)

Comment: Great info. Thank you very much for clearing that up!